# How do it make ```var num = 12;``` to be equal to 3 using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable `var num = 12;`
And I want to add both integers (`1 and 2`) in the num to equal 3 in JavaScript. I'm doing this to an array of elements that has two digit numbers.

Can someone solve this? I have tried and I need help.

Comment: Have you tried putting a  + symbol between 1 and 2? Like `var num = 1+2`

Comment: That is not what i'm trying to achieve. I'm actually doing this to an array of elements that have two digit number so that won't work.

Comment: I see. It would have been good to give these extra details in the question. Luckily several people seem to have guessed your goal regardless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn the number into an array of strings then use the map and reduce function to change them to numbers and add them together like so:

```js
let num = 12;
let sum = [...`${num}`].map(Number).reduce((a, b) => a + b);

or [...`${num}`].reduce((a, b) => +a + +b);
```

Comment: Wow it worked. Thanks

Comment: This is exactly what i need. I don't have a clear head now so i can't think it through. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm sorry guys all of you who contributed to this question. I wish I posted the code. I don't know why I didn't cross my mind. I'm so sorry but if you have a problem that is similar to what I'm saying here. Then I hope this answer or the answer below helps you.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a complete answer I can give you, but I can give you a workaround.

```js
function customStrictEquality(value1, value2) {
    if (value1 === 12 && value2 === 3) {
        return true;
    } else if (value2 === 12 && value1 === 3) {
        return true;
    } else if (value1 === value2) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't you just do `num = 3`?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
num.toString().split('').reduce((a,b) => parseInt(a)+parseInt(b),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String(12).split("").reduce((sum, d)=> sum += parseInt(d),0);
```

Works for any number.

Comment: Similar  to mine. Just difference to eyes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, partly inspired by Cristian Davide Conte.

This is an alternative algorithm which performs the summing numerically, without any conversion to strings (which is fine too!).

```js
function sumOfDigits(number) {
    if (parseInt(number) !== number || isNaN(number)) {
        throw new Error('the given number is not integer');
    }

    if (number < 0) {
        return -sumOfDigits(-number);
    }

    let sum = 0;
    while (number > 0) {
        let lastDigit = number % 10;
        sum += lastDigit;
        number = (number - lastDigit) / 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

It first ensures that the passed number is indeed an integer.
It handles the special case where a negative number is put in, by returning the negative checksum.

In each iteration the last digit is added to the sum and then that digit is subtracted from the number (which then has last digit 0) and the number is divided by 10 to remove the last digit. This is done until the number has been reduced to 0.

Answer (score 0):

And what about arithmetics?

```js
const num = 125;
const sum = (num - 1) % 9 + 1;
console.log(sum)
```